# Launch spring WebSocket programmatically

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

After some time I got my WebSocket running with this config:

```
@Configuration
//@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketServerConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(myHandler(), "/var").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler myHandler() {
        return new WebsocketServer();
    }
}
```

But I'm unable to find a way to launch this WebSocket from my code.

Is there a way to launch this WebSocket later in my program?

I found [this document](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RC1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/server/config/EnableWebSocket.html) but it does not provide a way to implement a `startWebSocket()` function or something similar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The document you linked shows an example, where it returns an instance of [EchoWebSocketHandler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-websocket-tomcat/src/main/java/samples/websocket/tomcat/echo/EchoWebSocketHandler.java).

You could accept connections and implement your own logic for *afterConnectionEstablished* or *handleMessage* using some internal status to determine whether you should accept *requests*, i.e.

```
@Configuration
 @EnableWebSocket
 public class MyConfiguration implements WebSocketConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addHandler(echoWebSocketHandler(), "/echo").withSockJS();
        }

        @Bean
        public WebSocketHandler echoWebSocketHandler() {
               //FooWebSocketHandler implements your specific logic
                return new FooWebSocketHandler();
        }
 }
 public class FooWebSocketHandler extends AbstractWebSocketHandler {
   private boolean enabled;
   ...
    public void handleMessage(WebSocketSession session,
                      WebSocketMessage<?> message)
               throws Exception {
     if (enabled) {//work
     } else {
       //disabled, i.e. throw exception or send data according to your api
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but with the `@EnableWebSocket` the WebSocket will be registered at startup of Spring. But I want to start the WebSocket later in my application. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Just edited the answer to always accept connections and setting internal status to decide whether the messages should be successfully handled or rejected.

Comment: Thanks :) this works.. But I had to implement the enabled Field in my WebSocketConfiguration class. Because if it is in the Websocket handler and is `@Autowired` the enabled will always be null.

Comment: Glad to know it works for you. I guess `enabled` would have been false by default (if declared as primitive `boolean`, not object type `Boolean`) but I agree it is simpler changing state into the configuration bean instead than instances created on the fly (unless you convert your handler into a service or something else).

Comment: Although this answer solves OP's problem, it does not answer the question